# Python, when nested function returns different variable then when called directly

Tags: python, python-2.7

Background:
beginner, working my way through Think Python.

I am at: Exercise 9.3. Write a function named avoids that takes a word and a string of forbidden letters,
and that returns True if the word doesn’t use any of the forbidden letters.
Modify your program to prompt the user to enter a string of forbidden letters and then print the
number of words that don’t contain any of them. Can you find a combination of 5 forbidden letters
that excludes the smallest number of words?

When I decided to try and write the script so it would answer the last question. "Can you find a combination of 5 forbidden letters that excludes the smallest number of words?"

Here is my Code:

```
    fin = open('words.txt')

    import itertools
    import string

    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
    forbidden = list(itertools.combinations(list(alphabet),5))

    def has_no_e(word,letter):
        return letter in word

    def avoids(word,f_let):
         index = 0
         while index < len(f_let):
             let = f_let[index]
             if let in word:
                  return True
             index += 1
         return False

    def count_word_wdout(f_list):
          count = 0
          for line in fin:
                xword = line.strip()
                if avoids(xword,f_list) == False:
                count += 1
          return count

    def max_words_wdout(fob_list):
          count = 0
          index = 0
          for char in fob_list:
              ncount = count_word_wdout(char)
              if count <= ncount:       
                  count = ncount
          print count

    max_words_wdout(forbidden)

    print count_word_wdout(forbidden[2])
```

Ok here is the problem:

With max_words_wdout(forbidden), ncount = count_word_wdout(char) calculates the first index, but the rest get returned as 0.

Yet 
print count_word_wdout(forbidden[2]) returns the correct value.

I have also tried this with a while loop, with the same results.

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem - but you missed an indentation after: `if avoids(xword,f_list) == False:`

Comment: yeah, getting the code across was a hassle, with all the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is that your file, `fin`, is being stored in global variable and you're reading all of its lines in `count_word_wdout`. This works once, but after that, the reading position is already at the end and there's never anything more to read.

To fix this, you either need to read the whole file up front and save all the words it contains in a variable that you can reference later, or reopen the file (or seek back to its start) and reread the file each time `count_words_wdout` is called.